# the size for values of type `(dyn SeekRead + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time

Tags: rust

**I'm trying to compile this code:**

```rust
use zip::read::ZipArchive;
use std::io::{Read, Seek};

trait SeekRead: Seek + Read {}

pub struct ArchiveZip<'a> {
    filename: &'a str,
    zip_archive: Box<ZipArchive<dyn SeekRead>>,
}
```

**And I'm getting this error:**

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn SeekRead + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/archive/zipfile.rs:10:18
   |
10 |     zip_archive: Box<ZipArchive<dyn SeekRead>>,
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   | 
  ::: ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/zip-0.5.11/src/read.rs:50:23
   |
50 | pub struct ZipArchive<R: Read + io::Seek> {
   |                       - required by this bound in `ZipArchive`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn SeekRead + 'static)`
```

**Isn't the `Box` supposed to avoid the problem of knowing the size at compile time?**

**Here is the Cargo build file:**

```
# cargo.toml
[dependencies]
zip = "0.5.11"
```

**And the definition for `ZipArchive`:**

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ZipArchive<R: Read + io::Seek> {
    reader: R,
    files: Vec<ZipFileData>,
    names_map: HashMap<String, usize>,
    offset: u64,
    comment: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Comment: How large do you think a `dyn SeekRead` is? The first member of `ZipArchive` would need to be one.

Comment: I don't understand how the size concepts fit together. How do I store a `ZipArchive` as a member of my `struct`?

Comment: The issue is that `ZipArchive<dyn SeekRead>` isn't a valid type since its impossible for `ZipArchive` to directly contain a `dyn SeekRead`. You'll need to use some form of indirection for the trait object, e.g. `ZipArchive<Box<dyn SeekRead>>`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a generic type in your struct as `ZipArchive` does. Notice that `ZipArchive` expects a specific type:

```rust
use zip::read::ZipArchive;
use std::io::{Read, Seek};

trait SeekRead: Seek + Read {}

pub struct ArchiveZip<'a, T: SeekRead> {
    filename: &'a str,
    zip_archive: Box<ZipArchive<T>>,
}
```